# Grails GORM refresh ignores fetch strategy

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an entity `Campaign` which has a many-to-many relationship with `Contact` using a join table `Recipient`.

```
class Campaign {
    ...
    static hasMany = [recipients: Recipient]
    ...
}

class Recipient {
    ...
    Contact contact
    static belongsTo = [campaign: Campaign]
    ...
}

class Contact {
    ...
}
```

Campaigns can have hundreds of thousands of contacts but because lazy fetch is default it's quick to retrieve a campaign from the database. However, when I call `campaign.refresh()` GORM tries to load all recipients and Grails runs out of memory.

```
List<Campaign> campaigns = Campaign.findAllWhere([status: CampaignStatus.STARTED])
campaigns.each { campaign ->
    if (campaign.refresh().isStarted()) {
        campaign.send();
    }
}
```

I turned logSql on see what's being executed. This code has been cleaned up for readability.

```
-- Campaign.findAllWhere
select * from campaign where (status=?)

-- campaign.refresh()
select * from campaign c left outer join recipient r on c.campaign_id=r.campaign_id where c.campaign_id=?
```

Why is the refresh joining to the recipient but the find query isn't?

Comment: Why you call refresh right after the `findAllWhere`? Or this two parts are separated in your original code?

Comment: The campaign.send() can be very slow, so I need to refresh each campaign just before I check the status to make sure it hasn't changed  in the mean time.

Comment: Not sure if will work, but how about:
campaigns.each { campaign ->
    def campaign2 = Campain.get(campain.id)
    campaign2.send();
}

Comment: @JavaDev I thought about but but because it's in the same Hibernate session it'll get the same campaign object and not fetch it from the database. I could try and evict it then get it again...

Comment: Maybe just try? Otherwise, there is a way to retrieve from another session using withNewSession

Answer (score 1):

For reference:

It is generally problematic to have huge collections mapped into a domain with hasMany/belongsTo since most operations are cascaded to the collection. This is why recipients are refreshed in your case but similar problems may arise in other business code around this domain.

This is not really GORM specific (though the cascading is set by GORM automatically) since these kinds of embedded collections would be mapped similarly in pure Hibernate/Java code.

In this case, it is better to separate Recipients from Campaign and not have the embedded collection at all in Campaign.

You may also try to define cascading manually for the recipients collection (and specifically leave out refresh)